# jQuery validation plugin addMethod to be accessible through attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I use bassistance jQuery validation plugin to validate my inputs.
I want to add a validation method with addMethod. The question is if it's possible to make this newly added method to be accessible through inputs attributes, like it works for other methods - type="email". I don't want to use it with rules option like this:

```
rules: {
    myField: { lettersonly: true }
 }
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about input types, but the easiest thing would be to add it using a class, like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('emailValidator', functiuon(val, elt) {
    // Your validation logic
}, 'Your error message');
```

And this could be your markup:

```
<input type="email" class="emailValidator" value="" />
```

Then call .validate() method as usual.